# I have created a class to manage my session storage in a blazor server app however i am struggling to get my dependency injection to work properly

Tags: asp.net-core, local-storage, blazor, blazor-server-side, session-storage

In my `program.cs` file, I am registering my class like this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<SessionStorageService>(x => new SessionStorageService(x.GetService<ProtectedLocalStorage>(), x.GetService<ProtectedBrowserStorage>()));
```

However the

```
x.GetService<ProtectedBrowserStorage>())
```

is always null as I get this error:

> No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage.ProtectedBrowserStorage' has been registered.

Comment: Regaeding the `DI in blazor app` lease refer to this [`offical document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server) for details implementation guideline

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you implement this:

[https://github.com/Blazored/SessionStorage/tree/main/src/Blazored.SessionStorage][1]

It works fine, to implement just create an extension for IServiceCollection, and call it on Startup.cs

```
services.AddServerStorage()
```

the extension should have this method.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddServerStorage(this IServiceCollection services) => AddServerStorage(services, null);
```

to call this:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddServerStorage(this IServiceCollection services, Action<SystemTextJsonOptions> configure)
        {
            return services
                .AddScoped<IJsonSerializer, SystemTextJsonSerializer>()
                .AddScoped<IStorageProvider, ServerStorageProvider>()
                .AddScoped<IServerStorageService, ServerStorageService>()
                .AddScoped<ISyncServerStorageService, ServerStorageService>()
                .Configure<SystemTextJsonOptions>(configureOptions =>
                {
                    configure?.Invoke(configureOptions);
                    if (!configureOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Any(c => c.GetType() == typeof(TimespanJsonConverter)))
                        configureOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new TimespanJsonConverter());
                });
        }
```